# PHP counter reset, redirect and no negative value

Tags: php, counter

I have this counter and everything is working great with it but i would like to modify it.
I cant code shit and i dont understand code but im tryiing my best and google stuff and test stuff by myself.

So what do i need it to do?
When 10 clicks are made a redirect is made to ''http://stackoverflow.com''
When 10 clicks are made the counter restarts.
The value cant reach negative like -1 -2 -3 etc.
If i click and close the site it counts it like -1 click or simplier sed it removes my click.

The code.

index.php

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60">

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

<title>AJAX &amp; PHP Click-Counter with Flat File Storage (text file)</title>
<!-- http://blog.fofwebdesign.co.uk/23-click-counter-with-flat-file-storage-text-file-ajax-php -->

<style>
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; font:16px/1.75 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif }
.page-content { padding:1em; max-width:64em; margin:auto }

.click-count { color:green; font-weight:bold }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="page-content">


<?php 

$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
 $tmp = explode('||', $line);
 $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
 }

?>

<center><b class="click-trigger" data-click-id="click-001">+1 click me</b> | <b class="click-trigger2" data-click-id="click-001">-1 click me</b>
| Clicked <span id="click-001" class="click-count"><?php echo $count['click-001'];?></span> times.</center>


<script>
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger'); // IE8
for(var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++){
 clicks[i].onclick = function(){
  var id = this.getAttribute('data-click-id');
  var post = 'id='+id; // post string
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', 'counter.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return; 
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
   };
  req.send(post);
  }
 }
</script>

<script>
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger2'); // IE8
for(var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++){
 clicks[i].onclick = function(){
  var id = this.getAttribute('data-click-id');
  var post = 'id='+id; // post string
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', 'counter2.php', true);
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return; 
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
   };
  req.send(post);
  }
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

counter.php (counts only +1 +1 +1 etc)

```html
<?php 

/* Notes - add items manually to 'counter.txt'
           one item per line, in this format;
           id||0
           e.g. click-005||0
           e.g. my-id||0
           e.g. download-01||0
*/

$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
 $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
 $item = trim($line[0]);
 $num = trim($line[1]);
 if(!empty($item)){
  if($item == $id){
   $num++; // increment count by 1
   echo $num;
   }
  $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
  }
 } 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

counter2.php ( counts - clicks like -1 -2 -3 etc)

```html
<?php 

/* Notes - add items manually to 'counter.txt'
           one item per line, in this format;
           id||0
           e.g. click-005||0
           e.g. my-id||0
           e.g. download-01||0
*/

$file = 'counter.txt'; // path to text file that stores counts
$fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // posted from page
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
 $line = explode('||', fgets($fh));
 $item = trim($line[0]);
 $num = trim($line[1]);
 if(!empty($item)){
  if($item == $id){
   $num--; // increment count by 1
   echo $num;
   }
  $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
  }
 } 
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

counter.txt ( stores the clicks )

```html
click-001||0
click-002||0
click-003||0
```

Comment: did you notice that you not have made a real question here? Should we refactor your _shit_ and answer to `So what do i need it to do?` that you have done it or not?